# What is the Basic Structure of a Function in FORTRAN?

Tags: c++, c, function, fortran

This is something that's I've wanted to know recently, mostly out of curiousity. I'm in the mood to learn some old coding styles, and FORTRAN seems like a good place to start.

I guess I should help you guys out by providing a good starting point.
So how would this C procedure be written in FORTRAN?

```
int foo ( int x , int y )
{
    int tempX = x ;
    x += y / 2 ;
    y -= tempX * 3 ;    // tempX holds x's original value.
    return x * y ;
}
```

I know the entire function could be a single line:

```
return ( x + ( y / 2 ) ) * ( y - ( x * 3 ) ) ;
```

But the point of me asking this question is to see how those four statements would be written individually in FORTRAN, not neccessarily combined into a single statement.

Comment: Pretty impressive, figuring out FORTRAN without a manual.

Comment: Why is this tagged C and C++?

Comment: "I'm in the mood to learn some old coding styles, and FORTRAN seems like a good place to start. " - why ? Could you explain what you ment by that ?

Comment: ldigas - yeah, it looks like FORTRAN is still being updated and used in modern development environments of sorts. I wasn't aware of this when I asked the question, and I had thought of FORTRAN as somewhat archaic. My mistake.

Comment: c4757p - It's tagged C/C++ because that's my starting point. I'm a C developer. But that's not entirely relavent, is it? Again, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you learn FORTRAN from? Just take a look at the [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fortran/Fortran_procedures_and_functions)!

Derived from the example, I'd say:

```
function func(x, y) result(r)
   integer, intent(in) :: x, y 
   integer             :: r 
   integer             :: tempX
   tempX = x
   x = x / 2
   y = y - tempX * 3
   r = x * y
end function foo
```

Comment: The questiomer asked about OLD coding styles - let's only have pure FORTRAN IV here, please :-)

Comment: Ha! I don't think I'm looking to get that specific yet. I'm just wanted to get a general idea. This looks pretty interest from the grammar perspective. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Neil Butterworth - FORTRAN IV. Don't you think that's a little too advanced ? :-)

Answer (score 7):

Don't blame me - you said *old* coding styles:

```
C234567
      SUBROUTINE FOO(I,J,K)
C SAVE THE ORIGINAL VALUES
      IORIG = I
      JORIG = J
C PERFORM THE COMPUTATION
      I = I + J/2
      J = J - IORIG*3
      K = I * J
C RESTORE VALUES
      I = IORIG
      J = JORIG
      END SUBROUTINE FOO
```

I shudder as I write this, but

- all variables are implicitly integers, since they start with letters between I and N
- FORTRAN passes by reference, so reset `I` and `J` at the end to give the same effect as the original function (i.e. pass-by-value, so `x` and `y` were unchanged in the calling routine)
- Comments start in column 1, actual statements start in column 7

Please, please, please never write new code like this unless as a joke.

Comment: Good grief Tim. Where did you dig that style out from ? :-)

Comment: Unfortunately it's quite similar to some of the code I've found floating around the office - I "solved" a problem a colleague had by giving him a subroutine that used a computed GOTO and he didn't realize I was kidding.  I resisted the urge here to post a sequence of images from http://www.kloth.net/services/cardpunch.php

Comment: Heh heh, guess what I have to maintain (and yes, it all looks like that)

Comment: This is why RATFOR was invented.

Answer (score 2):

See [Functions and Subroutines](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fortran/Fortran_overview#Functions_.26_Subroutines):

```
INTEGER FUNCTION foo(i, j)
...
foo = 42
END
```

then later:

```
k = foo(1, 2)
```

Comment: This is a great resource! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ndmeiri how's that?

Answer (score 2):

Your function might look like this in Fortran

```
 integer function foo(m, n)
 integer i

 i = m
 m = m + n/2
 n = n - i*3
 foo = m*n

 end function foo
```

You should be able to get started with any tutorial on Fortran. Some thing like this might help http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/fortran.html

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Similar to above, but with a main program to illustrate how it would be called.

```
C2345678
       program testfoo
         implicit none   
         integer r, foo 
         r = foo(4,5)
         print *, 'result = ', r
       end

       integer function foo(x,y)
         integer x, y
         integer tx, ty
         tx = x + y / 2
         ty = y - x * 3
         foo = tx * ty
         return
       end
```

Note that this is Fortran 77, which is what I learned 23 years ago.

Comment: You young whippersnappers, with your fancy "print *".  We had to do something like "WRITE(6, 100) R" and "100 FORMAT (9HRESULT = , I3)" in FORTRAN IV.

Comment: That can't possibly be the Fortran 77 they taught you 23 years ago - what are all those lower-case letters doing there? :)

Answer (score 0):

True old style in applying the rule IJKLMN for integer

```
C2345678
      FUNCTION IFOO(I,J)
      II = I + J/2
      JJ = J - I*3
      IFOO = II*JJ
      END
```

Comment: This is a very old question, maybe off-topic today (too broad). Do you believe your answer brings anything new?

Comment: I just remembered what I learnt 40 years ago. Nobody in that thread was using the coding style of that era. ;-)